# Image Analysis: sift / harris / affine / RANSAC

Tags: image-processing, transform, sift, keypoint

I am not sure if this falls under the criteria of a proper question, but still, I would like to give it a shot.

I am looking for a library or function that takes two SIFT descriptors in a form of a file (or a matrix) of [number_of_keypoints][feature_0...feature_127] - meaning 128 features per file and allows comparison of images (I am using harris-affine alg. to extract them: http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/affine/det_eval_files/extract_features2.tar.gz ).

I am interested in a method that would allow me to find mutual nearest neighbours, that would accept number of keypoints in the neighbourhood and success ratio.

E.g.
Lets say I have two files with keypoints (described by SIFT descriptor) (image_1.sift, image_2.sift). I would like the method to accept: number of keypoints in the neighbourhood, match ratio, where match ratio means in pseudo code:

```
For each keypoint in image_1
Pick 50 nearest neighbours from image_1 -> List<KeyPoints> neighbours_1
   For each keypoint in image_2
   Pick 50 nearest neighbours from image_2 -> List<KeyPoints> neighbours_2
int numberOfMatches = 0;
foreach(neighbour in neighbours_1)
{
    if(neighbour == neighbours_2.Find(neighbour))
        numberOfMatches++;
}
```

The ratio is number of matches to number keypoints taken into consideration.
For example FindMutualKeypoints(image_1,  image_2, 50, 0.7)

It can be c#, java, python or matlab implementation. I don't have much to do with image analysis on regular basis and before I start to write my own implementation, I assumed there probably is one out there already. I am having problem finding the correct terms in English from translation from my mother tongue (looks like the terms are quite different), which is probably the reason, why I could not find it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think openCV is the way to go.

Here is an example for it: [link](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html)
It uses SURF descriptors, but you can also use SIFT.

You then call the FLANN matcher which also give you information about the quality of the matches.